# jquery javascript places image over other image

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have one website want to sell the bottles with choice of caps.

This is reference site but it is in the flash.
http://harmanindia.com/mixandmatch.php

I want to write the script in such a way that the user can preview the each cap with each bottles so they can select the better choice.

Can anybody please provide me reference code which will help me to developed.

Thanks and advance.

Comment: Seems like all this can be done in standard html/javascript.

Comment: No I have list the bottles but I have to place the cap image over top of each bottle.

Comment: So what's the problem ? It can still be done with javascript quite easily

Comment: it can b done with javascript or Jquery .

Comment: Can you please provide me the rough idea of reference code so I can start working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please check this site which is create by me 
**Html Code**

```
<div class="img-swap">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a  class="active" href="">
        <span>
          One Sided
        </span>
        <img height="100" width="100" src="/images/product/51614099_business_cards01.png">
        <input type="hidden" value="/images/product/538734762_business_cards.png" class="oImg">
        <input type="hidden" value="/images/product/51614099_business_cards01.png" class="hImg">
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a class="inactive" href="">
        <span>
          Second Side
        </span>
        <img height="140" width="140" src="/images/product/2112217909_page_24.png">
        <input type="hidden" value="/images/product/2112217909_page_24.png" class="oImg">
        <input type="hidden" value="/images/product/1550391892_page_024.png" class="hImg">
      </a>
    </li>


  </ul>
</div>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
var oImg,hImg;

    jQuery('.img-swap li a:not(.active)').mouseover(function(){
        oImg = jQuery(this).find('.oImg').val();
        hImg = jQuery(this).find('.hImg').val();    
        jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src',hImg);
    });

    jQuery('.img-swap li a.active').mouseover(function(){
        oImg = jQuery(this).find('.oImg').val();
        hImg = jQuery(this).find('.hImg').val();    
        jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src',hImg);
    });

    jQuery('.img-swap li a:not(.active)').mouseout(function(){
        oImg = jQuery(this).find('.oImg').val();
        hImg = jQuery(this).find('.hImg').val();    
        jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src',oImg);
    });

    jQuery('.img-swap li a.active').mouseout(function(){
        oImg = jQuery(this).find('.oImg').val();
        hImg = jQuery(this).find('.hImg').val();    
        jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src',hImg);
    });

    jQuery( ".img-swap li a.active" ).each(function() {
          oImg = jQuery(this).find('.oImg').val();
          hImg = jQuery(this).find('.hImg').val();  
          jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src',hImg);
    });

    jQuery( ".img-swap li a.inactive" ).each(function() {
         oImg = jQuery(this).find('.oImg').val();
          hImg = jQuery(this).find('.hImg').val();    
          jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src',oImg);
    });
```

Comment: no this code is just swap the image src on hover.